# Spark: How to perform undersampling on LabeledPoint?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sampling

I've got some unbalanced data in my `LabeledPoint`. what I want to do is select all positives and `n` times more negatives (randomly). For example if I have a `100` positives and `30000` negatives, I want to create new `LabeledPoint` with all `100` positives and `300` negatives (`n=3`).

And in real scenario I don't how many positives and negatives I have on the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably your data is a `RDD[LabeledPoint]`. You can do something like the following:

```
val pos = rdd.filter(_.label==1)
val numPos=pos.count()
val neg = rdd.filter(_.label==0).takeSample(false, numPos*3)
val undersample = pos.union(neg)
```

You can find the docs for `takeSample`, `filter`, and `union` [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).